# Do I need to know Javascript, jQuery, JSP, PHP to make large scale complex android apps?

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, jsp

I know that JAVA is the main language used to make android apps. But is there any necessity of other languages such as Javascript, jQuery, JSP, PHP to make great android apps? please note that I am not talking about a simple "hello world" android app. I am talking about large scale complex apps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it dependes on what exactly the application does. If you require to have, for example, an API on a server to which you can make requests (and you want to develop the API yourself), you need to know those "languages". If the application is complex but it's contained within itself (that means that it doesn't require from you to develope on a server-side language), the only thing you need to know is Java.

On the other side, you don't NEED to develope those server-side applications yourself. You can build the app entirely on Java and consume the data from the servers, leaving the programming of the server-side applications to a third-party (like a freelancer).